# SQL Exception violation of primary key constraint when updating data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
private void FormRentBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        librarydb sorgu = new library();
        var book = from booklist in query.k_Books
                    join isrent in query.k_Bookstatus
                    on booklist.Book_statusId equals isrent.k_typeid
                    join booktype in query.k_BookType
                    on booklist.book_type equals booktype.ID
                    select new
                    {

                       booklist.Book_Name,
                       booklist.Book_Author,
                       booktype.Book_type,
                       booklist.Book_Page,
                       booklist.ID,
                       isrent.k_typecomment,
                    };
        bookscreen.DataSource = book.ToList();
        bookscreen.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Book Name";
        bookscreen.Columns[1].HeaderText = "bookscreen Author";
        bookscreen.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Book Type";
        bookscreen.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Page Number";
        bookscreen.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        bookscreen.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Book Status";
        bookscreen.Show();
        label6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    }
        public int a;
    private void bookscreen_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = bookscreen.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        label2.Text = bookscreen.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        a =int.Parse( bookscreen.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        label3.Text = bookscreen.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    }

k_Rentedbooks rent = new k_Rentedbooks();
rent.renter_id = Login.k_id;
rent.renter_id = int.Parse(bookscreen.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
rent.rent_date = DateTime.Now;

DateTime return = DateTime.Now;
int day;
day = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

rent.returndate = return.AddDays(day);
db.k_Rentedbooks.Add(rent);

var updatebook = db.k_Books.Where(w => w.ID ==a).FirstOrDefault();
updatebook.Kitap_statusId = 2;
db.SaveChanges();
```

i need to add data to k_KiralananKitaplar and update a row named Kitap_DurumId = 2 but i can only add data or update i cant do in one time db.SaveChanges give me error

Here's a sample of the data:

- Kitap_Adi = book name,
- Kitap_Yazar = book_author,
- Kitap_Tur = book type,
- Kitap_Sayfa = book page,
- Kitap_DurumId = book status

[image]

The error message is

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_k_KiralananKitaplar'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.k_KiralananKitaplar'. The duplicate key value is (0).

Comment: Please don't make us guess what the error is - be more specific and include information like that in your question.

Comment: Here is a good example of why you use English for naming your classes, interfaces, variables etc. I have only understood two things: you use `DateTime` and it is somehow related to `Login`s. It is also somehow related to books if Kazakh "kitap" is the same as Turkish "kitap" :)

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can improve the quality of your questions in future.

Comment: As for the rest of you commenting here, the salt about the lack of an error (looking at you @J.Steen) and the discussion about naming conventions is hardly relevant. True, it would help us to help OP if the names were descriptive for us, but they aren't what's causing the problem. If we aren't able to discern what the code is doing and assist OP in spite of language barriers, then we shouldn't be addressing this question in the first place.

Comment: i changed all of to english sorry i am newbie

Comment: @Ortund I've edited the salt right out. It was a venting of the frustration that comes with seeing tons of low quality questions just pouring in, day to day. However, fair point, and accepted.

Comment: @J.Steen I feel you man, I review low quality posts daily... Lately I've been feeling like "this post has to be SO testing me to see if I'm paying attention"... And then it isn't :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update statement:

```
var updatebook = db.k_Books.Where(w => w.ID ==a).FirstOrDefault();
updatebook.Kitap_statusId = 2;
db.SaveChanges();
```

You're selecting a record where `Id == a` using `FirstOrDefault` and given that EntityFramework can't update this record, I'm going to assume that no record exists where `Id == a` so you need to handle a null return value from your query:

```
var updatebook = db.k_Books.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID == a);

if (updatebook != null)
{
    updatebook.Kitap_statusId = 2;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this case, if a record was returned by the query, it'll update `Kitap_statusId`, otherwise, it won't do anything.

### Update

Per OP comment on this question:

> i solved problem but now i need to find when i insert new data in a table other table insert to same table to how can i do that

You just need to get the Id values of the newly insert entity and use that to insert a record into the 2nd table.

So in your code you have the first item being inserted:

```
db.k_Rentedbooks.Add(rent);
```

When you do the `SaveChanges()` for this, it'll automatically update the entity with its new Id, so lower down in that function you can then add a new record to the 2nd table using the Id value for `rent`.

As a rough example:

```
var Book = new Book{ statusId = rent.Id };
db.SecondTable.Add(Book);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: a taking value from data grid view content

Comment: Please update your question and include the data grid view code and a sample of the data (try to convert it to English so that people can understand more easily - it will make it easier for us to help you).

Comment: @FahriBilici please also include the error message you get when you try `SaveChanges()`

Comment: @Orttund any help ?

Comment: @FahriBilici More information is required. What I can tell you is that you're changing data in a column that is referenced by another table which SQL Server won't let you do. Please show relationships for this table

Comment: i solved problem but now i need to find when i insert new data in a table other table insert to same table to how can i do that

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please don't forget to Accept the answer.